# Inncorect date is being sent to mongo query from nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am facing very strange behavior when running a query on server side(nodeJS with mongoose and mongoosePaginate)

I am querying a data base for a range of dates,
During the whole process I can see that I am sending the correct range,
But in execution time, it is actually sending an incorrect date as you can see below :
[image]

now the $gte is what i am looking for 
but i keept hetting values from 28/2/2018.
what i found is if i am printing the query object to the console 
this is what $gte value is : 
[image]

what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What is your query and what is your mongo version ? Mongodb works with Utc date. So behind the scene your local date is converted to Utc. So GMT +2 means your local time is ahead two hours from GMT time. In 3.6 you can pass tz along with date value.

Comment: Hi,
the my Mongo version is 3.6.2
and this is my query:
       `query = {
                    "date": {
                        $gte: new Date(fromYear+"-"+(+fromMonth)+"-"+fromDay)
                    }
                    ,
                    $and: [
                        {
                            "date": {
                                $lte: new Date(toYear+"-"+toMonth+"-"+getLastDayOfMonth(fromMonth))
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }`